# Given a finite set of polynomials, is there an algorithm to determine if they generate the polynomial ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra

For a finite set of polynomials $p_1, \dots, p_m \in \mathbb{C}[t_1,\dots, t_n]$, is there a deterministic algorithm to determine whether $\langle p_1,\dots, p_m \rangle=\mathbb{C}[t_1,\dots, t_n]$? Regardless of the answer, I would welcome references to work in this vein.

Comment: You can look for algorithms that compute the reduced Grobner basis of the ideal, though as you may know this approach is rather demanding. The most elementary ways to do it are with variants of Buchberger's algorithm. A fine introduction to the subject is the textbook *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms: An Introduction to Computational Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra* by Cox, Little and O'Shea.

Comment: Before writing your own code for computing the reduced Grobner basis, try firing up Macauley 2 and see if it succeeds on the polynomials of interest: https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/TryItOut/  You can try various monomial orders -- some may work when others don't.

Comment: Thanks! My specific question is actually slightly different, and I'm wondering if this matters: I have homogeneous polynomials and want check whether their only common root is 0. This amounts to asking whether $\langle p_1,\dots, p_m \rangle \supseteq I_s$ for some $s \geq 1$, where $I_s$ is the ideal of polynomials of degree $\geq s$.

Comment: Have you tried resultants? For example, $p_1=(x-a)(x-b)$ and $p_2=(x-c)(x-d).$ The resultant eliminating $x$ is $(a - c) (b - c) (a - d) (b - d)$ and this is $0$ iff they have a common root.

Comment: @Somos I have not. This is an excellent suggestion! It seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, and is built in to Macaulay 2: http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.13/share/doc/Macaulay2/Resultants/html/_resultant.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compute the reduced Grobner basis and see if it's $(1)$.